# Symfony 2 doctrine fixtures load

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php c:\wamp\www\symfony\app\console doctrine:fixtures:
load

Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle' not     found in
C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php on line 17

Call Stack:
0.0000     234000   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\console:0
0.0650    3390144   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\wamp\
www\Symfony\app\console:27
0.0770    3622600   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->d
oRun() C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\
Application.php:124
0.0770    3622824   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() C:\wamp\w
ww\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\App
lication.php:70
0.0770    3623104   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundle
s() C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2303
0.0770    3623512   6. AppKernel->registerBundles() C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\
bootstrap.php.cache:2473
```

Line 17 in AppKernel is correct and the file DoctrineBundle exist where it should be.

Anyone knows what is the reason of error?

Answer (score 0):

The Error is clear. You add doctrine bundle to appKernel, but you don't install it (or bad install it ).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you add to AppKernel the requested namespace bundle (Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle) before composer ends the installation command.

Try to delete line 17 in the AppKernel, then a `composer update` and after composer updated your vendors, replace the line 17 as it was